# UITableview Logic

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to print below format in UITableview cell

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
```

NOTE: without using any array

below is my code for even and odd behaviour

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    int number=(int)indexPath.row;
    if(indexPath.row%2==0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"even  %d ",number];
        NSLog(@"even indexNumber=%d",number);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"odd   %d ",number];
        NSLog(@"odd indexNumber=%d",number);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is problem?

Comment: i need to print above sequence in my table without using any array.

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (indexPath.row/2)];`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its already answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code snippet to print the tableview in desired format.

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.row/2];
```